# Weblogic log filter and replacement

Tags: java, logging, filter, weblogic

In weblogic, am I able to change the output of the logs? For example, right now, there are some logs that are really long:

[ERROR] Calling blah resulted in
java.blahException : cause

at ...

at ...

at ...

at ...

... and so on for a really really long stack trace.

so my question is, am I able to filter out this entire stack trace, and replace it with only a one line message of [ERROR] Calling blah resulted in: java.blahException : cause?

since doing so would greatly reduce the clutter in the log file.

Comment: If it's your code causing the exception - of course you can catch it and do something else. If it's weblogic... you can turn down the logging level from the Admin Console (go to your Server link and then the logging tab). What is the actual exception - not `blah`? The best solution - of course - is to fix the error, not reduce logging.

Comment: In my case, it is a SocketException : Connection reset. But there are also other exceptions that I wish to handle, such as innate problems with the Escenic engine. The escenic problem was fixed in ver. 5.7 but due to circumstances it is not possible to perform this upgrade, and since it's not causing any problems, i would like to shorten the stacktrace to 1 line